# Можно ли с помощью JS реализовать постепенную загрузку файлов стилей сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

Допустим: сначала загружается шапка. Первым делом загружается HTML код и стиль header.css Дальше с плавной анимацией появляется остальной контент сайта, CSS стили подключаются, остальной HTML код становится видимым, как они грузятся. Это нужно лезть в бэкенд и AJAX, или возможно на обычном JS? Если возможно - дайте подсказку, как, дальше я уже сам погружусь в тему.

Comment: А HTML-CSS настолько огромные, чтобы была проблема с их загрузкой? Если вопрос не про загрузку, а про "постепенно показывать", то setTimeout или событие 'scroll' - scrollTop и т.п. Ну, большие картинки можно хранить как массив строк, и догружать их в .src по мере необходимости, если их не очень много.

Comment: Можно 1) Динамически добавлять линки на css - файлы (не пробовал). 2) Можно... самому читать css-ки парсить их и програмно создавать классы. Вот только не всё, пожалуй, получится разпарсить...

Comment: В раздел `head` в теге `<style>...</style>` добавляете стили первого видового экрана, все остальные стили в `<link ... />`. Оптимизируете скрипты, изображения, выкидываете слайдеры и всё пучком. То, что хотите вы - будет периодически блокировать пользовательский интерфейс.